# add jsp file to another jsp file and have the servlet read it as a whole,

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**I want to include lines of jsp code into another jsp file, where the servlet only sees appended lines of code from both files. I wan it to build the file all at once, rather than included page first and then the parent page.**

What I've done:

I had server errors when I used include file. It built the included page first when I used the include page. Tried templating with tags but I kept getting the error shown below, but all the code was copied and pasted from another stackoverflow answer.

> HTTP Status 500 - /web/templateTest.jsp (line: 4, column: 0) No tag "genericpage" defined in tag library imported with prefix "t"

I mostly just want my question answered, that being whether or not there is a way to include files so that they are read as a whole. However it would be nice to know what i'm doing wrong with the tags if someone can identify it. this is my templateTest.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>    
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:genericpage>
    <jsp:attribute name="header">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="footer">
        <p id="copyright">Copyright 1927, Future Bits When There Be Bits Inc.</p>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <p>Hi I'm the heart of the message</p>
    </jsp:body>
</t:genericpage>
```

below is my genericpage.tag file in the WEB-INF/tags folder

```
<%@tag description="Overall Page template" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="header" fragment="true" %>
<%@attribute name="footer" fragment="true" %>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="pageheader">
      <jsp:invoke fragment="header"/>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <jsp:doBody/>
    </div>
    <div id="pagefooter">
      <jsp:invoke fragment="footer"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'll say it again, I mostly just want my question answered, that being whether or not there is a way to include files so that they are read as a whole. However it would be nice to know what I'm doing wrong with the tags if someone can identify it.

Comment: Provide the relevant code to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you might not declare the tag library which has defination of tag "t"

i hope it resolves your query

Comment: I wanted my question answered: is there a way to include files so that they are read as a whole

Comment: Are you appending jsp file as jsp:include or include directive ?

Comment: I tried both and neither do I what i wanted it to do. As I said in my question: 
"I had server errors when I used include file. It built the included page first when I used the include page."

Comment: i guess you might have missed some of the configuration regarding custom tags. See this link for more info. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't show more, my answer will be : use `@include` to include to second file into the first. That way the inclusion occurs at the source level.